# Multisite Multi domain setup in PWA

Tags: magento2, pwa, multisite

I usually do multisite multi-domain setup in Magento site and it works fine.
I have another site that uses PWA and I have all basic steps as we do to create multisite with multi domain but it is not working properly and css and other files showing 404 errors.

Is there any other configuration to set up inside PWA?

So far I have done the below steps.

1. Created the main site with PWA and working fine.
2. Created 4 Websites, Store and Store views for multisite multi-domain.
3. Chnaged `base_url` of all sites to different domains.
4. Chnaged `pub/index.php` file and put switch case statement to assign values based on domain

> $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $runCode;
> $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $runType;

6. Created 4 new domains inside CPanel and changed the document root folder of all 4 domains to the main site where I have installed Magento and PWA.

I get below error

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: What is the error message you see in the network tab? Are CSS files throwing 404? If so, check if the URL is correct or not. I dont think there is any specific configuration related to PWA's css.

Comment: @Ahmad kindly check my updated question.